# Using a counter to run a model every n frames on Android

Tags: mediapipe

I am new to mediapipe and I want to know if it is possible to run a tflite model every n frames?
For example I only want to run the palm detection model once every 10 frames instead of continuously on a Android not Python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can create your own calculator that counts the frames. What I ended up doing was making my own custom flow limiter calculator that had a count for each non dropped frame.

Based on this count you can add an Allow packet (Boolean) as output to the flow limiter calculator and use the Allow packet with a gate calculator to stop or start certain models (palm detection) every n counts.